# Using cartesian coordinates in application

Tags: java

A player starts the game in the 0 coordinate (x=0,y=0). When the user clicks on the screen, it returns the coordinates of the mouse click(x1, y1). Now the player has to move from its current position A(0.0) to B(x1,y1). But for example **x1>y1** so in my while loop y will get value of y = (y1-1) earlier than x.

What do I need to do so that **x** and **y** get final values x = (x-1) y = (y1-1) at the same time?

```
while(cont){
    if(x1 > x){
        x++;
    }else if(x1 < x){
        x--;
    }
    if(y1 > y){
        y++;
    }else if(y1 < y){
        y--;
    }
    frame.repaint();
    sleep(); // Thread.sleep(200)
}
```

Comment: erm... DOES NOT COMPUTE.

Comment: Is your question "How do I move my guy in a straight line to the destination?"

Comment: Well that is just a part of y code... to khelwood my question "How do I move a guy in twisted, curved lines to destination". Also why my question get so negative votes?

Comment: Because it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @user2865835 a) you haven't provided SSCCE (http://sscce.org/), b) your problem definition is vague at best, c) the problem doesn't show any *real* research effort on your part. Currently, the answer is "to get values x = (x-1) y = (y1-1), use `x--;` and `y = y1 - 1;`... Also, "to move a guy in twisted, curved lines" you should `give him something strong to drink - absinthe preferably`.

Comment: OK Guy coordinates(0,0) and I press on the screen(100,12) x = 100 y = 12, so I need to increase x value by one 100 times and y value only 12 times.

Comment: @user2865835 So work out the ratio: everytime you change the x position by 1,you need to move the y by: ____

Comment: @Quirliom the problem is that, as far as I understand OP, he tried to do that with integer arithmetics, and it's essentially unsolvable that way, as you won't get smooth movement that way; you'd have to use floating point arithmetic with rounding to translate to proper screen coordinates. If he hadn't figured that by now, I seriously doubt he'll understand any explanation other than an explicit solution. And I don't think we should feed free fish to no-one...

Comment: to hell with me, I'll give him an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose what you want is along this lines: (providing the code lacking for SSCCE You /OP/ hadn't given Us)

```
// float x0, y0; // old position
// float x1, y1; // requested position
// float x = x0, y = y0; // current position
// float total_steps; // total steps to split the move between
// float step_x = ( x1 - x0 ) / total_steps;
// float step_y = ( y1 - y0 ) / total_steps;

while( Math.round(x) != x1 ) {
    x += step_x;
    y += step_y;
    frame.repaint();
    sleep(); // Thread.sleep(200)
}
```

I don't even know what I could explain here, because a) it can't get any simpler than this, b) I'm still unsure what the whole question was about.